# Automapper adding mapping with an additional external collection

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have automapper correctly mapping, but I have an external collection of which I want to use to enrich the outgoing class.

I can obviously have the list bought into the profile class but this list is from an api which I will call before I run my automapper on run time. A crude example below of wanting to see the country code on the player class based on the country name.

Mapping  in my class implementing Profile interface

```
CreateMap<StagePlayer, Player>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.PlayerName))
    .ForMember(x => x.SomethingA, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Something))
    .ForMember(x => x.CountryName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.CountryName )) //obviously don't need this but just for the sake of the example
    //.ForMember(x => x.CountryCode = countries.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CountryName == x.CountryName)?.CountryCode)
    ;
```

Actual Usage.

```
var playersOut = playersIn.Select(s => _mapper.Map<Player>(s)).ToList();
playersOut.ForEach(x => x.CountryCode = countries.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CountryName == x.CountryName)?.CountryCode);
```

I want the ForEach setting of the countrycode inside my profile but be forced to pass in a list of countries into the mapping call.

I cannot find any examples of this and I am sure I am missing something extremely obvious, but cannot see it in the automapper documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the countries variable is available in the mapping code you can just do something like this

```
CreateMap<StagePlayer, Player>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.PlayerName))
    .ForMember(x => x.SomethingA, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Something))
    .ForMember(x => x.CountryName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.CountryName )) //obviously don't need this but just for the sake of the example
    .ForMember(x => x.CountryCode, x => x.MapFrom(y => countries.FirstOrDefault(z => z.CountryName == y.CountryName)?.CountryCode));
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I agree that ideally I would like the countries variable in the mapping, but I do not know how to pass it in. I do not want to pass it in through my class constructor as it will be run time populated

_public class PlayerMapping : Profile
 public PlayerMapping()
 CreateMap....
..._

Comment: Can you set countries as some static collection? It seems to me that data isn't really going to change anytime soon.  This is not really an automapper issue, more of an issue with data and availability of data.